# paintComponent() and paint() - drawing JButton with decorator pattern

Tags: java, swing, decorator, paint, paintcomponent

I found a decorator pattern example with Swing component. The following code is drawing three buttons on a `JFrame`. One of the button has slash on it and implemented with Decorator pattern. The original one has paint() method, but I replaced `paint()` with `paintComponent(Graphics g)`, then it fails to draw lines on the button. Is it impossible to use `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()`? If possible how to do that? What is the problem of this trial? What I am missing?

Original code link is [Decorator pattern in Java](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Design-Pattern/DecoratorpatterninJava.htm).

```
public class DecoWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton Quit;

    public DecoWindow() {
        super("Deco Button");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();

        getContentPane().add(jp);
        jp.add(new CoolDDecorator(new JButton("Cbutton")));
        jp.add(new SlashDDecorator(new CoolDDecorator(new JButton("Dbutton"))));        
        jp.add(Quit = new JButton("Quit"));
        Quit.addActionListener(this);
        setSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        setVisible(true);
        Quit.requestFocus();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        new DecoWindow();
    }
}

class DDecorator extends JComponent {
    public DDecorator(JComponent c) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add("Center", c);
    }
}

class SlashDDecorator extends DDecorator {
    int x1, y1, w1, h1;

    public SlashDDecorator(JComponent c) {
        super(c);
    }

    public void setBounds(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
          x1 = x; y1 = y;
          w1 = w; h1 = h;
          super.setBounds(x, y, w, h);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          super.paintComponent(g);
          Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
          g2d.setColor(Color.red);
          g2d.drawLine(0, 0, w1, h1);
    }
}

class CoolDDecorator extends DDecorator {
    boolean mouse_over; //true when mose over button

    JComponent thisComp;

    public CoolDDecorator(JComponent c) {
        super(c);
        mouse_over = false;
        thisComp = this; //save this component
        //catch mouse movements in inner class
        c.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                mouse_over = true; //set flag when mouse over
                thisComp.repaint();
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                mouse_over = false; //clear flag when mouse not over
                thisComp.repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    //paint the button
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); //first draw the parent button
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        //if the mouse is not over the button
        //erase the borders
        if (!mouse_over) {
            Dimension size = super.getSize();
            g2d.setColor(Color.lightGray);
            g2d.drawRect(0, 0, size.width - 1, size.height - 1);
            g2d.drawLine(size.width - 2, 0, size.width - 2, size.height - 1);
            g2d.drawLine(0, size.height - 2, size.width - 2, size.height - 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`paint()` calls `paintComponent()` then `paintChildren()`. Your component is painting the slash and returning from `paintComponent()`. Then the default `paint()` implementation moves on, eventually painting the children, which are those buttons, which then just paint right ontop of your slash.

Your IDE should let you place a breakpoint in your paint code. You can check the callstack to see what's going on. If you aren't using an IDE, you can look at what Swing is doing by looking at JComponent.java in src.zip within your JDK.

Why do you want to use `paintComponent()` anyway?

Comment: (1+) See: [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Oracle docuement linkand handling UI of subclasses of JComponent more precisely.

Comment: I added more `public void paintBorder(Graphics g) { super.paintBorder(g); } and public void paintChildren(Graphics g) { super.paintChildren(g); }` in SlashDDecorator class and DDecorator class. But I cannot see the slash on a slash button.

Comment: The problem is that paintChildren is going to paint OVER your slash. You have to prevent  paint children from executing after your paintComponent. Calling super.paintChildren isn't preventing the children from painting. Once you prevent the children, you'll see the slash but not the button. I think you're going to have to override paint, not paintComponent to get what you want.